# c++ how to use std::mutex and std::lock_guard with functor?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am learning how to use `std::thread` in standard C++, and I can't solve one problem with `std::mutex`.

I am running 2 threads with simple functions that show a message in CMD. I want to use a `std::mutex`, so that one thread will wait until the other threat stops using the buffer.

When I use the functions everything works fine, but with the functors I have a problem:

> error C2280: 'std::mutex::mutex(const std::mutex &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

class thread_guard
{
    private:
        std::thread m_thread;
    public:
        thread_guard(std::thread t)
        {
            m_thread = std::move(t);
            if (!m_thread.joinable())
                std::cout << "Brak watku!!!" << std::endl;
        }
        ~thread_guard()
        {
            m_thread.join();
        }
};

class func
{
    private:
        std::mutex mut;
    public:
        void operator()()
        {           
            for (int i = 0; i < 11000; i++)
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mut);
                std::cout << "watek dziala 1" << std::endl;
            }
        }
};

class func2
{
    private:
        std::mutex mut;
    public:
        void operator()()
        {           
            for (int i = 0; i < 11000; i++)
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mut);
                std::cout << "watek dziala 2" << std::endl;
            }
        }
};

std::mutex mut2;

void fun()
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < 11000; i++)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mut2);
        std::cout << "watek dziala 1" << std::endl;     
    }
}

void fun2()
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < 11000; i++)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mut2);
        std::cout << "watek dziala 2" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    thread_guard t1( (std::thread( func() )) );
    thread_guard t2( (std::thread(func2() )) );
    //thread_guard t1((std::thread(fun)));
    //thread_guard t2((std::thread(fun2)));
}
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21409439/error-c2280-attempting-to-reference-a-deleted-function

Comment: The error states that you are trying to copy a mutex (calling the copy constructor), which obviously is not allowed.

Comment: but i'm do the same like with function but inside the class. So where is the problem??

Answer (score 2):

You actually have *two* problems. The compilation error is because the function objects are *copied*, but the embedded mutex doesn't have a valid copy-constructor so you get an error. Instead you have to create an instance of your object, and pass the member function and a pointer to the object:

```
func f1;
thread_guard t1(std::thread(&func::operator(), &f1));
```

Note that this doesn't really make it useful to use a function in this case.

---

The other problem is that each functor object have it's own mutex, so the two threads will run completely independent of each other.

If you, for example, make the mutex global, then you also solve the first problem, and can use the functor without problems.

Answer (score 1):

In your code each `function` owns a mutex. These are different mutexes, and really they don't guard anything.

The problem is that a function needs to be copyable and mutexes are not. If the function needs to lock a mutex it is usually to some shared resource and you'd pass this mutex by reference to your functor.

Create the mutex outside, e.g. in main(), then

```
class func
{
    std::mutex * mutex;

public:
    explicit func( std::mutex & m ) : mutex( &m )
    {
    }

    void operator()()
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < 11000; i++)
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(*mutex);
            std::cout << "watek dziala 1" << std::endl;
        }
    }     
};
```

similar for func2

```
int main(void)
{
   std::mutex mutex;
   thread_guard t1( (std::thread( func( mutex) )) );
   thread_guard t2( (std::thread( func2( mutex ) )) );
```

}